# How to run an arbitrary script on a pod after Helm Chart installed it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

Use case: I am forced to use an unflexible chart, which doesnt externalize some important properties to Values.yml.

So I want to touch those manually after the pod is created.

I dont want to make the chart public here , but here as an example:

Imagine there is a kubernetes yaml which creates a simple pod from a modified postgresql image.

```
containers:
      - name: my-psql
        image: modded-postgres
        env:
           - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
             value: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
```

The modded-postgres image differs from the official one in a way ,that there is no entrypoint , only cmd.

What should I do to init the db with some init.sql?

I can't touch neither  the image nor the the yaml. The yaml resides inside a chart which I have to use as a subchart.

What are my possibilities? Can I run some helm script after pod creation? Or what about to launch other pod which will connect to this crappy postgres pod and make the db from the there?

Comment: Fork the chart and possibly the Docker image.  (You can create a Docker image `FROM` the third-party image and customize it.)  Since Kubernetes can delete and recreate pods without your intervention, a workflow that depends on manually `kubectl exec` anything will be inherently unreliable.

Comment: For the very specific workflow you're describing, another possibility is to `kubectl port-forward` a connection to the database server once it's started and use `psql` locally to seed the database.  But that depends on it being really exactly-once configuration for persistent data, which may or may not match your real use case.